# css: how can I make sure one html element is always at the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

Say I have this html code:

```
<html>  
<body>   
<div id="Div1" style="position:relative">
   <span style="position:absolute;top:100px">My text</span>
</div> 
<div id="Div2">
Test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to make Div2 always below Div1 regardless of the content of Div1? Because the span uses position:absolute  in Div1,  the content of Div2 appears above the content of Div1.

Comment: Please paste the css you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason div2 displays above div1 is because div2 is absolutely positioned.  That means that div1 doesn't participate in the normal document flow, as if it was pulled out of the document.  So, div2 shows up at the top, then your absolute positioning pushes div1 down to 100px.

Take the absolute positioning off of div1, then use margins or padding to move it down to the desired location.  That way, the normal html rendering will place div2 below div1.

If you're forced to absolutely position div1, then you need to absolutely position div2 as well.  You may need to use javascript to figure out the height of div1 and set the top of div2 appropriately.

```
<html>  
<body>   
<div id="Div1" style="position:absolute; top: 100px;">
   <span>My text</span>
</div> 
<div id="Div2" style="position:absolute; top: 130px;">
Test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just nest Div2 into that span/div and put margin-top on it and voala... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this ?

```
<div id="Div1" style="margin-top:100px">
   <span>My text</span>
</div> 
<div id="Div2">
Test
</div>
```

I don't quite get why you are doing it that way. Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: i've edited my answer, this should work... unless you really need to have absolute positioning all over the place

Comment: Basically I have 2 Divs and I want Div2 to be below any content of Div1. In reality, Div1 contains some images and these images are located within the Div1 using absolute positioning. I would like the content of Div2 to be below those images which are in Div1.

Comment: What you did work but you changed the question. The content of Div1 is positioned using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered this question correctly about position:relative vs. position:absolute and page flow in the container div.

Just to add to the answer. I found the following tutorial really helpful when I was learning about positioning in CSS.

[Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff: div is as standard block elements, so that wont make any difference.

You could try:

```
<div id="Div1" style="position:relative; display:inline-block">
  <span style="position:absolute;top:100px">My text</span>
</div> 
<div id="Div2">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make any difference. Div2 still appears above Div1.

Answer (score 0):

do you want div2 below div1 or at the very bottom of the page? if you want it below div1 then add

```
clear:both;
```

to div2.

if you want it fixed to the bottom of the page then use a fixed position property on the div2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="Div1" style="position:relative">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0">just some text<br />very long text<br />very long text<br />very long text<div id="Div2" style="margin-top:30px">div thats always below(30px's below)</div></div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

use display:block; on those divs

Comment: Indeed. It doesn't make any difference.